# push from a side bar menu to another view controller in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, sidebar, uistoryboardsegue

I use in my application, the side bar menu like in facebook, so I have different cells in this menu, what I want is to when click on a cell push me to another view controller. I face a problem here which is: the menu is a table view which I don't have it in storyboard, I use some classes from [this site:github](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo)

and I've stucked here, in my application I use a storyboard, but this menu is programmed with code, and doesn't have a view in stroyboard,

in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method: I use like this

```
    for(int j=0; j< 9 ; j++)
    {
               if(indexPath.row == j)
               {
                     DetailsSidebarViewController *essayView = [[DetailsSidebarViewController alloc]  init];
               essayView.detailItem = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:j];
        NSLog(@"%@=%d",essayView.detailItem,j);
               }
     }
```

and I create a DetailsSidebarViewController as the new view controller when I push from menu item. in this class, I create a method to configure the view, and just I echo the result:

```
- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {

        NSLog(@" %@ ", self.detailItem);


    }
}
```

the result is true like I want, but I want to push to another view controller, in fact nothing is happened when I click on an item into the menu.

How can I create the new view controller in storyboard? if the menu has not a storyboard, and how can I connect them with segues?

In fact, I am blue with it, please help!!

Comment: the library you are using is way old compare to what is available noe. Try taking a look at cocoa controls site. There much easier ones available for free. I like the ECSliding and it is very easy to munuplate.

Comment: please can you post a link!

Comment: https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an instance of the App Delegate class in the Side Menu view controller, and push it from there. You must have a reference to the Side Menu View and a reference to the Center View! Import your App Delegate into the Side Menu controller, and in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, use:

```
 DetailsSidebarViewController *essayView = [[DetailsSidebarViewController alloc]  init];
 essayView.detailItem = [jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // note that you don't need the for loop to know what object you need
 AppDelegate* myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [myAppDelegate.sideMenuViewController toggleSideMenu]; // the idea here is that you have to close the side menu, i.e. it must dissapear
 [myAppDelegate.centerViewController.navigationController pushViewController:essayView animated:YES];
```

This is all the code you need.
If I may, as a piece of advice, use [Mike Frederik's MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) instead of the library you're using. In my opinion, it has a more simple and a more straightforward implementation, just look into the README file, everything is explained pretty simple, and it has exactly the code you need!
Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: thank you, I will try one of them (Mike Frederik's MFSideMenu ), and then I will give you a feedback :)